# Serialization issue with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, twitter4j, morphia

Using Morphia 1.1.1. with Mongo 4.0.5 Snapshot, storing User objects from Twitter4J.

I get this error when retrieving an Object "User" from Mongo:

```
org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: No usable constructor for [Ltwitter4j.GeoLocation;
```

The relevant part of the object, serialized in Json in Mongo looks like:

```
    "favoriteCount" : 4,
    "place" : {
        "name" : "Kewaunee",
        "countryCode" : "US",
        "id" : "0114d7a909aa6731",
        "country" : "United States",
        "placeType" : "city",
        "url" : "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/0114d7a909aa6731.json",
        "fullName" : "Kewaunee, WI",
        "boundingBoxType" : "Polygon",
        "boundingBoxCoordinates" : [ 
            {
                "className" : "[Ltwitter4j.GeoLocation;"
            }
        ],
        "accessLevel" : 0
    },
```

I checked and actually added a no-arg public constructor in the source of the GeoLocation class. And what's this "[L" thing in front of the package name, and the ";" at the end?

Answer (score 0):

`GeoLocation` needs a no-arg constructor to be deserialized.  So it's probably not going to work to use that directly.  The `[L` bit means that the type is an array.

Also, what is Mongo 4.0.5 Snapshot?  There's nothing from Mongodb with a name/version like that.  The latest database version 3.2.6(? i think i just saw that release) and the Java driver is at 3.2.2.

Comment: I must have confused the version number. I did add a no arg constructor to the source of the GeoLocation class, so what gives?

Comment: You've updated the twitter4j lib you got via maven?  You'll need to take care to replace the downloaded bits with your updated bits.